# IAR print environment variable string : Preprocessor Defined symbols

Tags: c, jenkins, environment-variables, preprocessor, iar

As part of our Jenkins build, Jenkins has many environment variables. Two of them are BUILD_NUMBER and BRANCH_NAME. We add these to the Preprocessor Defined symbols:

[image]

Those environment variables are now accessible at compile time:

```
#define APPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR         (1)
#define APPLICATION_VERSION_MINOR         (1)
#define APPLICATION_VERSION_BUILD         (BUILD_NUMBER)
#define GIT_BRANCH_NAME                   (BRANCH_NAME)
```

using the BUILD_NUMBER is fine, it is a number, but I get an error when trying to use the BRANCH_NAME. For example:

```
debug(DEBUG_LEVEL_INFO, "software version %d.%d.%d  branch %s", APPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR, APPLICATION_VERSION_MINOR, APPLICATION_VERSION_BUILD, GIT_BRANCH_NAME);
```

I get the error:

```
Error[Pe020]: identifier "localbuild" is undefined D:\repo\source\state_machine.c 284
```

The environment variable BRANCH_NAME is set to "localbuild", the compiler is getting the correct value. But, how do can I use it in my code? It works for numbers, but how do I do the same for strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, a string environment variable must be added like this:
BRANCH_NAME="$_BRANCH_NAME_$"

Answer (score 1):

Consider using:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x)         #x
#define EVALUATE_STRING(x)   STRINGIFY(x)
#define GIT_BRANCH_NAME      EVALUATE_STRING(BRANCH_NAME)
```

If you have those definitions plus:

```
#define BRANCH_NAME localbuild
```

(that's probably set on the command line with something like `-DBRANCH_NAME=localbuild` — usually, you can't access environment variables from the C preprocessor), and you then use it:

```
printf("Git branch name [%s]\n", GIT_BRANCH_NAME);
```

the output looks like:

```
printf("Git branch name [%s]\n", "localbuild");
```

Comment: thanks! that's a useful trick. IAR does allow you to access environment variables from its C preprocessor. It's just no very well documented.

Comment: Intriguing — thanks for the info.  I've dumped a 'usually' qualifier into my answer because it remains the case that most C preprocessors do not allow you to access the environment.

Comment: If you have IAR, search the help for $_ENVVAR_$: The Windows environment variable ENVVAR. Any name within $_ and _$ will be expanded to that system environment variable. It's really useful when using build system like jenkins- where there is a lot of environment variables available